# Opencart how unserialize(): Error is generated while saving data to database

Tags: php, serialization, opencart, notice

how this error is generated

> **PHP Notice:  unserialize(): Error at offset 11 of 55 bytes in /catalog/model/account/address.php on line 124 - index.php?route=checkout/payment_address/save**

And

> **PHP Notice:  unserialize(): Error at offset 11 of 55 bytes in /catalog/model/account/address.php on line 196 - index.php?route=checkout/payment_address**

i want to controll such issue. it saved 4 or many payment address but with errors. retriving record from database

```
'iso_code_2'     => $iso_code_2,
            'iso_code_3'     => $iso_code_3,
            'address_format' => $address_format,
            'custom_field'   => unserialize($result['custom_field'])
```

insertion of record in database

```
,  custom_field = '" . $this->db->escape(isset($data['custom_field']) ? serialize($data['custom_field']) : '') . "'
```

Comment: The custom_field value is not always serialized, so it would be logical that you can't unserialize it every time

Comment: data store in the field is ' a:1:{i:8;s:115:"Please if any of my above choices of clothes have a small size, I'd prefer it.but if not then it's fine.thanks'   so here you see the serlization not done properly so that's why it generate error at unserlization, i want to stop wrong data entering to database

Comment: What kind of field is custom_field, a varchar?

Comment: the type of field is text

Comment: some time it store data like **a:1:{i:8;s:43:"Please delivery on march  5 thank you.** .. so i want to trace such error .. it usually generate on mobile